# How do I merge one directory into another using Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, command-line, sh

I'm looking for shell script that merge files from one directory into another.

Sample:

```
html/
  a/
    b.html
  index.html

html_new/
  a/
    b2.html
    b.html
```

Usage:

```
./mergedirs.sh html html_new
```

Result:

```
html/
  a/
    b.html
    b2.html
  index.html
```

`html/a/b.html` was replaced by `html_new/a/b.html`
`html/a/b2.html` was copied from `html_new/a/b2.html`
`html/index.html` was kept untouched

Comment: Tried `cp -r html_new/* html` ? You can remove `html_new` directory afterwards.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You probably just want `cp -R $1/* $2/` — that's a recursive copy.

(If there might be hidden files (those whose names begin with a dot), you should prefix that command with `shopt -s dotglob;` to be sure they get matched.)

Comment: Are the trailing slashes important here?

Answer (score 111):

```
cp -RT source/ destination/
```

All files and directories in `source` will end up in `destination`. For example, `source/file1` will be copied to `destination/file1`.

The `-T` flag stops `source/file1` from being copied to `destination/source/file1` instead. (Unfortunately, `cp` on macOS does not support the `-T` flag.)

Comment: works nicely, it copies and merges /folder/data to folder2/data

Comment: I pefer this solution because it works "as is" with .dotfiles.

Comment: On Mac OS X / darwin you'll want to use `cp -r source/ destination` -- it's tricky you have to use the / exactly as indicated.

Comment: Proud to be the one upvoting this answer and so making it now equals to the current accepted one .

Comment: Please note is will overwrite any files in destination which have the same name as the source

Answer (score 18):

Take a look at rsync

```
rsync --recursive html/ html_new/
```

Notice that the trailing slash `/` matters in this case. If you omit it from the source argument, `rsync` will write the files to `html_new/html/` instead of `html_new/`.

Rsync has got a lot of flags to set so look at rsync manpage for details.

Answer (score 8):

Just use rsync - it's a great tool for local file copy and merging in addition to remote copying.

```
rsync -av /path/to/source_folder/ /path/to/destination_folder/
```

Note that the trailing slash on the source folder is necessary to copy only the contents of source_folder to the destination. If you leave it off, it will copy the source_folder *and* it's contents, which is probably not what you are looking for since you want to merge folders.

Comment: there is small typo, extra hyphen, so it should be `rsync -av /path/to/source_folder/ /path/to/destination_folder/`

Answer (score 6):

Even though this question and its accepted answer are ancient, I am adding my answer because the presently existing ones using `cp` either don't handle some edge-cases or require working interactively. Often edge-cases/scriptability/portability/multiple-sources don't matter though, in which case simplicity wins, and it is better to use `cp` directly with less flags (as in other answers) to reduce cognitive load - but for those *other* times (or for a robustly reusable function) this invocation/function is useful, and incidentally isn't bash-specific (I realise this question was about bash though, so that's just a bonus in this case). Some flags can be abbreviated (e.g. with `-a`), but I have included all explicitly in long-form (except for `-R`, see below) for the sake of explanation. Obviously just remove any flags if there is some feature you specifically *don't* want (or you are on a non-posix OS, or your version of `cp` doesn't process that flag - I tested this on GNU coreutils 8.25's `cp`):

```
mergedirs() {
    _retval=0
    _dest="$1"
    shift
    yes | \
        for _src do
            cp -R --no-dereference --preserve=all --force --one-file-system \
                  --no-target-directory "${_src}/" "$_dest" || { _retval=1; break; }
        done 2>/dev/null
    return $_retval
}

mergedirs destination source-1 [source-2 source-3 ...]
```

Explanation:

- `-R`: has subtly different semantics from `-r`/`--recursive` on some systems (particularly with respect to special files in source dirs) as explained in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18712/difference-between-cp-r-and-cp-r-copy-command#18718)
- `--no-dereference`: never follow symbolic links in SOURCE
- `--preserve=all`: preserve the specified attributes (default: mode,ownership,timestamps), if possible additional attributes: context, links, xattr, all
- `--force`: if an existing destination file cannot be opened, remove it and try again
- `--one-file-system`: stay on this file system
- `--no-target-directory`: treat DEST as a normal file (explained in in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109704), namely: `If you do a recursive copy and the source is a directory, then cp -T copies the content of the source into the destination, rather than copying the source itself.`)
- [piped input from `yes`]: even with `--force`, in this particular recursive mode `cp` still asks before clobbering each file, so we achieve non-interactiveness by piping output from `yes` to it
- [piped output to `/dev/null`]: this is to silence the messy string of questions along the lines of `cp: overwrite 'xx'?`
- [return-val & early exit]: this ensures the loop exits as soon as there is a failed copy, and returns `1` if there was an error

BTW:

- A funky new flag which I also use with this on my system is `--reflink=auto` for doing so-called "light copies" (copy-on-write, with the same speed benefits as hard-linking, and the same size benefits until and in inverse proportion to how much the files diverge in the future). This flag is accepted in recent GNU `cp`, and does more than a no-op with compatible filesystems on recent Linux kernels. YMWV-a-lot on other systems.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't `cp -r` work?

```
cp -r html_new/* html
```

or (since the first version won't copy ".something" files)

```
cd html_new; cp -r . ../html
```

Please note that `-r` **reads from pipes** if any of the files in the copied directory are pipes. To avoid that, use `-R` instead.

Comment: When "merging" multiple directories etc. consider also `-n` (no clobber) or `-f` (force) option to either keep existing files or overwrite them.

Answer (score 2):

```
cd html
cp -r . /path/to/html_new
```

Answer (score 1):

> cp --recursive --no-target-directory [--no-clobber] "[IN]" "[OUT]"

- `--no-target-directory`: Treat OUT as a normal file, so include files starting with **dot** (hidden files).
- `--no-clobber`: If you don't want to overwrite **existing** files. Inner dirs are never overwritten anyway.